# How can I deploy a worker role into azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have an mvc4 web application working in azure.
I have now created a worker role which works as an email (reminders) sender.

How should I deploy this worker role into azure? 
Creating a cloud service through management portal doesn't seem right.. I don't see how will this worker role be connected to my web site?

I use a Git for managing deployments. Can I just commit and push my worker role? This doesn't seem enough..

Once deployed, how will I be able to stop this service?

I would really much appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Azure Cloud Service is fine, and you could use a technology like Azure Storage Queues as a communication mechanism between the MVC 4 web app and the worker role.

Alternatively, you could host an ASP.NET Web API endpoint in your worker role and expose that. See [this blog post](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/host-aspnet-web-api-in-an-azure-worker-role).

Starting and stopping the service can be done via the Azure portal.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the quick response. Would you be so kind as to provide a reference on how to use Azure Storage Quieries for this purpose?

Comment: Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/queue-service/) covering this.

Comment: Thanks Mark. BTW, are Storage Queries really necessary? When working locally, all I add for it to work is to add a reference to the Web solution, to the EntityFramework.dll and edit the web.config file. However, once I published the worker role into azure, it now says the instance is unhealthy and status is recycling.

Comment: I would agree with @MarkBerryman that using the storage queues in this manner is ideal. 

If there's a problem with your sender, or it can't handle a backlog, the queues will store the workload (reliably) until the sender is back up again.

Comment: @Brett, Mark, thanks to both. I was able to correctly deploy the worker role. However, I am having some trouble when trying to access the information in my database. I've posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18089541/access-sql-azure-from-worker-role). Any adivse?